# Undefined operation: "-zf-bp-to-em(0) gt 0em" when compiling foundation

Tags: sass, gulp, zurb-foundation

When compiling foundation 6 using gulp I receive this error

```
Undefined operation: "-zf-bp-to-em(0) gt 0em on line 82 of ../bower_components/foundation-sites/scss/util/_breakpoint.scss from line 12 of ../scss/main.scss
```

I understand that it's saying that it can't perform this kind of operation, but I'm using all the default foundation scss files included so I'm not sure how to make sure it knows how to do this kind of operation.

in main.scss I have

```
// Sass utilities
@import '../bower_components/foundation-sites/scss/util/breakpoint';
@import '../bower_components/foundation-sites/scss/util/color';
@import '../bower_components/foundation-sites/scss/util/mixins';
@import '../bower_components/foundation-sites/scss/util/selector';
@import '../bower_components/foundation-sites/scss/util/unit';
@import '../bower_components/foundation-sites/scss/util/util';
@import '../bower_components/foundation-sites/scss/util/value';

// Global variables and styles
@import '../bower_components/foundation-sites/scss/global';

// Components
@import '../bower_components/foundation-sites/scss/grid/grid';
@import '../bower_components/foundation-sites/scss/typography/alignment';
@import '../bower_components/foundation-sites/scss/typography/base';
@import '../bower_components/foundation-sites/scss/typography/helpers';
@import '../bower_components/foundation-sites/scss/typography/print';
@import '../bower_components/foundation-sites/scss/typography/typography';
@import '../bower_components/foundation-sites/scss/forms/checkbox';
@import '../bower_components/foundation-sites/scss/forms/error';
@import '../bower_components/foundation-sites/scss/forms/fieldset';
@import '../bower_components/foundation-sites/scss/forms/forms';
@import '../bower_components/foundation-sites/scss/forms/help-text';
@import '../bower_components/foundation-sites/scss/forms/input-group';
@import '../bower_components/foundation-sites/scss/forms/label';
@import '../bower_components/foundation-sites/scss/forms/select';
@import '../bower_components/foundation-sites/scss/forms/text';
@import '../bower_components/foundation-sites/scss/components/visibility';
@import '../bower_components/foundation-sites/scss/components/float';
@import '../bower_components/foundation-sites/scss/components/button';
@import '../bower_components/foundation-sites/scss/components/button-group';
@import '../bower_components/foundation-sites/scss/components/accordion-menu';
@import '../bower_components/foundation-sites/scss/components/accordion';
@import '../bower_components/foundation-sites/scss/components/badge';
@import '../bower_components/foundation-sites/scss/components/breadcrumbs';
@import '../bower_components/foundation-sites/scss/components/callout';
@import '../bower_components/foundation-sites/scss/components/close-button';
@import '../bower_components/foundation-sites/scss/components/drilldown';
@import '../bower_components/foundation-sites/scss/components/dropdown-menu';
@import '../bower_components/foundation-sites/scss/components/dropdown';
@import '../bower_components/foundation-sites/scss/components/flex-video';
@import '../bower_components/foundation-sites/scss/components/label';
@import '../bower_components/foundation-sites/scss/components/media-object';
@import '../bower_components/foundation-sites/scss/components/menu';
@import '../bower_components/foundation-sites/scss/components/off-canvas';
@import '../bower_components/foundation-sites/scss/components/orbit';
@import '../bower_components/foundation-sites/scss/components/pagination';
@import '../bower_components/foundation-sites/scss/components/progress-bar';
@import '../bower_components/foundation-sites/scss/components/reveal';
@import '../bower_components/foundation-sites/scss/components/slider';
@import '../bower_components/foundation-sites/scss/components/sticky';
@import '../bower_components/foundation-sites/scss/components/switch';
@import '../bower_components/foundation-sites/scss/components/table';
@import '../bower_components/foundation-sites/scss/components/tabs';
@import '../bower_components/foundation-sites/scss/components/title-bar';
@import '../bower_components/foundation-sites/scss/components/top-bar';
@import '../bower_components/foundation-sites/scss/components/thumbnail';
@import '../bower_components/foundation-sites/scss/components/tooltip';
```

and my breakpoint.scss contains

```
// Foundation for Sites by ZURB
// foundation.zurb.com
// Licensed under MIT Open Source

////
/// @group breakpoints
////

// scss-lint:disable ZeroUnit

/// A list of named breakpoints. You can use these with the `breakpoint()` mixin to quickly create media queries.
/// @type Map
$breakpoints: (
  small: 0,
  medium: 640px,
  large: 1024px,
  xlarge: 1200px,
  xxlarge: 1440px,
) !default;

$-zf-zero-breakpoint: small !default;

@if nth(map-values($breakpoints), 1) != 0 {
  @error 'Your smallest breakpoint (defined in $breakpoints) must be set to "0".';
}
@else {
  $-zf-zero-breakpoint: nth(map-keys($breakpoints), 1);
}

/// All of the names in this list will be output as classes in your CSS, like `.small-12`, `.medium-6`, and so on. Each value in this list must also be in the `$breakpoints` map.
/// @type List
$breakpoint-classes: (small medium large) !default;

/// Generates a media query string matching the input value. Refer to the documentation for the `breakpoint()` mixin to see what the possible inputs are.
///
/// @param {Keyword|Number} $val [small] - Breakpoint name, or px, rem, or em value to process.
@function breakpoint($val: $-zf-zero-breakpoint) {
  // Size or keyword
  $bp: nth($val, 1);
  // Value for max-width media queries
  $bp-max: 0;
  // Direction of media query (up, down, or only)
  $dir: if(length($val) > 1, nth($val, 2), up);
  // Eventual output
  $str: '';
  // Is it a named media query?
  $named: false;

  // Orientation media queries have a unique syntax
  @if $bp == 'landscape' or $bp == 'portrait' {
    @return '(orientation: #{$bp})';
  }
  @else if $bp == 'retina' {
    @return '(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), (min-resolution: 192dpi)';
  }

  // Try to pull a named breakpoint out of the $breakpoints map
  @if type-of($bp) == 'string' {
    @if map-has-key($breakpoints, $bp) {
      @if $dir == 'only' or $dir == 'down' {
        $bp-max: -zf-map-next($breakpoints, $bp);
      }

      $bp: map-get($breakpoints, $bp);
      $named: true;
    }
    @else {
      $bp: 0;
      @warn 'breakpoint(): "#{$val}" is not defined in your $breakpoints setting.';
    }
  }

  // Convert any pixel, rem, or unitless value to em
  $bp: -zf-bp-to-em($bp);
  @if $bp-max {
    $bp-max: -zf-bp-to-em($bp-max) - (1/16);
  }

  // Conditions to skip media query creation
  // - It's a named breakpoint that resolved to "0 down" or "0 up"
  // - It's a numeric breakpoint that resolved to "0 " + anything
  @if $bp > 0em or $dir == 'only' or $dir == 'down' {
    // `only` ranges use the format `(min-width: n) and (max-width: n)`
    @if $dir == 'only' {
      // Only named media queries can have an "only" range
      @if $named == true {
        // Only use "min-width" if the floor is greater than 0
        @if $bp > 0em {
          $str: $str + '(min-width: #{$bp})';

          // Only add "and" to the media query if there's a ceiling
          @if $bp-max != null {
            $str: $str + ' and ';
          }
        }

        // Only use "max-width" if there's a ceiling
        @if $bp-max != null {
          $str: $str + '(max-width: #{$bp-max})';
        }
      }
      @else {
        @warn 'breakpoint(): Only named media queries can have an `only` range.';
      }
    }

    // `down` ranges use the format `(max-width: n)`
    @else if $dir == 'down' {
      $max: if($named, $bp-max, $bp);

      // Skip media query creation if input value is exactly "0 down",
      // unless the function was called as "small down", in which case it's just "small only"
      @if $named or $bp > 0em {
        @if $max != null {
          $str: $str + '(max-width: #{$max})';
        }
      }
    }

    // `up` ranges use the format `(min-width: n)`
    @else if $bp > 0em {
      $str: $str + '(min-width: #{$bp})';
    }
  }

  @return $str;
}

/// Wraps a media query around the content you put inside the mixin. This mixin accepts a number of values:
///  - If a string is passed, the mixin will look for it in the `$breakpoints` map, and use a media query there.
///  - If a pixel value is passed, it will be converted to an em value using `$global-font-size` as the base.
///  - If a rem value is passed, the unit will be changed to em.
///  - If an em value is passed, the value will be used as-is.
///
/// @param {Keyword|Number} $value - Breakpoint name, or px, rem, or em value to process.
///
/// @output If the breakpoint is "0px and larger", outputs the content as-is. Otherwise, outputs the content wrapped in a media query.
@mixin breakpoint($value) {
  $str: breakpoint($value);

  // If $str is still an empty string, no media query is needed
  @if $str == '' {
    @content;
  }

  // Otherwise, wrap the content in a media query
  @else {
    @media screen and #{$str} {
      @content;
    }
  }
}

/// Convers the breakpoints map to a URL-encoded string, like this: `key1=value1&key2=value2`. The value is then dropped into the CSS for a special `<meta>` tag, which is read by the Foundation JavaScript. This is how we transfer values from Sass to JavaScript, so they can be defined in one place.
/// @access private
///
/// @param {Map} $map - Map to convert.
///
/// @returns {String} A string containing the map's contents.
@function -zf-bp-serialize($map) {
  $str: '';
  @each $key, $value in $map {
    $str: $str + $key + '=' + -zf-bp-to-em($value) + '&';
  }
  $str: str-slice($str, 1, -2);

  @return $str;
}

/// Find the next key in a map.
/// @access private
///
/// @param {Map} $map - Map to traverse.
/// @param {Mixed} $key - Key to use as a starting point.
///
/// @returns {Mixed} The value for the key after `$key`, if `$key` was found. If `$key` was not found, or `$key` was the last value in the map, returns `null`.
@function -zf-map-next($map, $key) {
  // Store the values of the map as a list, so we can access them with nth
  $values: map-values($map);

  // Ghetto for loop
  $i: 1;
  $found: false;
  @each $val in map-keys($map) {
    @if $found == false {
      @if ($key == $val) {
        $found: true;
      }
      $i: $i + 1;
    }
  }

  // If the key doesn't exist, or it's the last key in the map, return null
  @if $i > length($map) {
    @return null;
  }
  // Otherwise, return the value
  @else {
    @return nth($values, $i);
  }
}

/// Get a value for a breakpoint from a responsive config map. If the config map has the key `$value`, the exact breakpoint value is returned. If the config map does *not* have the breakpoint, the value matching the next lowest breakpoint in the config map is returned.
/// @access private
///
/// @param {Map} $map - Input config map.
/// @param {Keyword} $value - Breakpoint name to use.
///
/// @return {Mixed} The corresponding breakpoint value.
@function -zf-get-bp-val($map, $value) {
  // Check if the breakpoint name exists globally
  @if not map-has-key($breakpoints, $value) {
    @return null;
  }
  // Check if the breakpoint name exists in the local config map
  @else if map-has-key($map, $value) {
    // If it does, just return the value
    @return map-get($map, $value);
  }
  // Otherwise, find the next lowest breakpoint and return that value
  @else {
    $anchor: null;
    $found: false;

    @each $key, $val in $breakpoints {
      @if not $found {
        @if map-has-key($map, $key) {
          $anchor: $key;
        }
        @if $key == $value {
          $found: true;
        }
      }
    }

    @return map-get($map, $anchor);
  }
}

// Legacy breakpoint variables
// These will be removed in 6.3
$small-up: null;
$small-only: null;
$medium-up: null;
$medium-only: null;
$large-up: null;
$large-only: null;
$xlarge-up: null;
$xlarge-only: null;
$xxlarge-up: null;
$xxlarge-only: null;

@if map-has-key($breakpoints, small) {
  $small-up: screen;
  $small-only: unquote('screen and #{breakpoint(small only)}');
}

@if map-has-key($breakpoints, medium) {
  $medium-up: unquote('screen and #{breakpoint(medium)}');
  $medium-only: unquote('screen and #{breakpoint(medium only)}');
}

@if map-has-key($breakpoints, large) {
  $large-up: unquote('screen and #{breakpoint(large)}');
  $large-only: unquote('screen and #{breakpoint(large only)}');
}

@if map-has-key($breakpoints, xlarge) {
  $xlarge-up: unquote('screen and #{breakpoint(xlarge)}');
  $xlarge-only: unquote('screen and #{breakpoint(xlarge only)}');
}

@if map-has-key($breakpoints, xxlarge) {
  $xxlarge-up: unquote('screen and #{breakpoint(xxlarge)}');
}
```

Comment: Having this same problem

Comment: I'm having the same issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe @import '../../bower_components/foundation-sites/scss/util/mixins'; BEFORE you import the other utils

```
// Sass utilities
@import '../bower_components/foundation-sites/scss/util/unit';
@import '../bower_components/foundation-sites/scss/util/breakpoint';
@import '../bower_components/foundation-sites/scss/util/color';
@import '../bower_components/foundation-sites/scss/util/mixins';
@import '../bower_components/foundation-sites/scss/util/selector';
@import '../bower_components/foundation-sites/scss/util/util';
@import '../bower_components/foundation-sites/scss/util/value';
```

Answer (score 5):

Try adding:

```
@import 'util/_unit';
```

above

```
@import 'util/breakpoint';
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me.  Makes sense, since -zf-bp-to-em is in _unit